# How to query a table not to include data if id exists on the related table?

Tags: php, mysql

Here's my tables.

**Notification Table**

```
+----+--------------+
| Id | Subject      |
+----+--------------+
| 1  | Loreum Ipsum |
| 2  | Hello World  |
| 3  | Pls Help     |
+----+--------------+
```

**UserNotification Table**

```
+----+----------------+--------+
| Id | NotificationId | Status |
+----+----------------+--------+
| 1  | 1              | Read   |
+----+----------------+--------+
```

I want to query notification table without including data if `NotificationId` exists on the `UserNotification` Table

I want result:

**Notification Table**

```
+----+-------------+
| Id | Subject     |
+----+-------------+
| 2  | Hello World |
| 3  | Pls Help    |
+----+-------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`NOT EXISTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM Notification n
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM UserNotification u
    WHERE n.Id = u.NotificationId
);
```

### [`sql fiddle demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f231/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can use not in

```
select Id,Subject from notificationTable
where Id not in (select Id from userNotificationTable) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You also can use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT n.*
FROM Notification n
JOIN UserNotification un
ON n.Id <> un.NotificationId
```

#### SQLFiddle Demo

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like ..

```
Select * from Notification
left join UserNotification on Notification.id = UserNotification.NotificationId
where UserNotification.id is null
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/606917/1)**

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by `LEFT JOIN` with `NULL` check:

```
SELECT N.Id, N.Subject
FROM `Notification` N
LEFT JOIN `UserNotification` U ON U.NotificationId = N.Id
WHERE U.NotificationId IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NOT IN

```
Select * from Notification where id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM UserNotification)
```

This sql will help for get data

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT n.Id, n.Subject FROM Notification n
LEFT JOIN UserNotification nu on nu.NotificationId = n.id
WHERE nu.id IS NULL
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

you want to return the notification that are no in usernotification

try this :

```
select Id,Subject
from Notification  
where 
id not in (
select distinct NotificationId  from UserNotification
)
```

Comment: every one is selecting the id from usernotification but they should select the id of the notification  "notificationId" it's a foreign key no!!!